# Creating multiple elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new here and look for a way to create multiple elements by using jquery.

Here's an example. I create a table and append a row. How could i include 4 rows more without using createElement?

```
function table(){
    $(document.createElement("table")).appendTo($('body'))
    $(document.createElement('tr')).appendTo($('table'))
}
```

Comment: Why use this mix `jquery/pure js` ? `$( "body" ).append( "<table><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr></table>" );` instead for example

Comment: Alternative if you don't want to build a string is to use `.appendTo` to return the newly appended element `var tbl = $("<table>").appendTo("body"); var tr = $("<tr>").appendTo(tbl); cols.forEach(c => tbl.append("<td>"))` etc

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it's been usefull and iv'e learnt from it

Answer (score 0):

You do not need createElement if you use jQuery

```
$("body").append(`<table id="table1">
  <thead><tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`)
```

Or have a loop:

```js
const rows = Array.from({length:4}).map((_,i) => `<tr><td>Row ${i} Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>`).join("")
$("body").html(`<table><tbody>${rows}</tbody></table>`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new and started using jquery quiet recently. You solved my question and i learnt something new and easy.